# How to remove AM/PM from the formatted date in moment.js

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I have been using moment.js to format dates and I dont need either AM or PM to be displayed with the time. But it seems its not working properly. When its a morning time(AM) the date displayed as PM. But in evening(PM) either AM nor PM displayed.And I need to translate the date to Swedish, In Swedish the formatting works as intended but after translating to english its not working properly.

**Example outputs-**
Last modified: May 23, 2018, 8:06 PM

Last modified: May 23, 2018 15:36

**Expected outputs -**

Last modified: May 23, 2018, 8:06

Last modified: May 23, 2018 15:36

Below is my code.

```
getUpdatedDate(date){

      return moment(date).locale('sv').format('DD MMMM YYYY HH:mm');
  }
```

Comment: what is the version of moment? and what is `date` here ? is it a Date object?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/gtunboo2/1/ seems fine to me, can't reproduce your issue.

Comment: do you want to show or hide AM/PM completely ?

Comment: I need hide both AM and PM completely